# How to do? Now Typing... in chat app

Tags: objective-c, ios8, chat

I am working on chat app.
[image]
I want to show how if my friend is typing something then in my end the chat window will show.. **Now typing...**

i know a bit about code (to judge but not sure), but where to call api or its done by some  sort of chat server's property ?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (range.length > 0)
    {
         // Friend is deleting
    }
    else
    {
        // Friend is typing
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the networking?

Comment: we are using simple Server using php web services...

Comment: Well detecting that a user is typing something into a text field is trivial (use the search on here to see), but transmitting it to the server is much more complicated.  I think you are focusing on the wrong element of the problem.

Comment: yes...agreed,transmitting it to server is complicated...as every time we need to send/hit API

Comment: Aren't you using XMPP for chat? Is it a normal REST service call? Based on the comments I read (after my answer) It seems you are using PHP web service for Posting message and getting it back.

Comment: Yes its simple REST service call,but i want to know the proceedure,is it server based service ?

Comment: You are not left with much options as you are using REST client. In REST client you need to call the service for post only. As normal servers are 1 directional mean you send a request and you will get a response. The answer I mentioned is for pure chat (using XMPP). XMPP server uses socket connection and it has bi-directional communication. For your issue you need to call the service only.

Comment: thanks@KapilChoubisa for defining it...Accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2:**
My answer was based on XMPP as the question says it is a chat app. Chat app generally use XMPP protocol. For your requirement here is the solution you can use:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
       // Deleting. This will call multiple time so it's on you if you want to implement it. It may be optimize at some level.
       // You can use performSelector withDelay & cancelSelectors etc.
   }
   else {
       //Typing
       if (textField.text.length == 0) {
           // TextField is empty right now and the user has began typing. So call the service with typing status. 
           //This condition is useful to prevent web service call every time user type.
       }
   }
}
```

**Edit1:**

Check the [XEP-0022](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html). This seems proper to achieve your needs.

When A is typeing (Send a message from user A's client):

```
 <message
    from='a@server.com'
    to='b@server.com'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
      <composing/>
      <id>message22</id>
    </x>
 </message>
```

B's client will receive following:

```
 <message
      from='a@server.com'
      to='b@server.com'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
          <composing/>
          <id>message22</id>
      </x>
</message>
```

Now you can handle the response and show the things accordingly.

**Original:**

There is a [XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) available for the chat state. When you detect modification in textfield you can send following stanza as mentioned in link:

```
<message 
    from='bernardo@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    to='francisco@shakespeare.lit/elsinore'
    type='chat'>
   <composing xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
</message>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't that depend if the OP is using that networking protocol?

Comment: No, it depends on how you are communicating with the other person.  There are hundreds of ways.

Comment: @trojanfoe please explain the mechanism used